# Logging RestAssured Logs to Log4J in Junit tests

Tags: logging, log4j, rest-assured

We are using REST Assured for testing some REST services. We need to redirect the request and response logging to Log4j log. We have following code in an attempt to test the logging redirection:

```
public class RestTest {
    private static RequestSpecification spec;
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RestTest.class);
    @Rule
    public TestWatcher watcher = new Log4JWatcher();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initSpec(){
    PrintStream logStream = IoBuilder.forLogger(logger).buildPrintStream();
    RestAssuredConfig restAssuredConfig = new RestAssuredConfig();
    LogConfig logConfig = restAssuredConfig.getLogConfig(); 
    logConfig
        .defaultStream(logStream)
        .enablePrettyPrinting(true);

    spec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
        .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .setBaseUri("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
            .addFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
            .setConfig(restAssuredConfig)
            .build();
    
}

@Test
public void useSpec(){
    given()
        .spec(spec)
        .param("limit", 20)
        .when()
        .get("posts")
        .then()
        .statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

We get the following log output to log4j file:

```
09:47:17.264 [main] INFO  test.util.Log4JWatcher - useSpec(test.ExtentReportSandbox.RestTest)
09:49:45.485 [main] INFO  test.util.Log4JWatcher - useSpec(test.ExtentReportSandbox.RestTest)
```

On system.out we see the REST Assured output of request and response. That output is not redirected to the Log4j file. How do we get the console output redirected to Log4j file?

Comment: Please remove "solved" from your title and move your solution to its own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing following:

```
        new RequestLoggingFilter();
    new ResponseLoggingFilter();
    spec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .setBaseUri("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addFilter(ResponseLoggingFilter.logResponseTo(logStream))
            .addFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.logRequestTo(logStream))
            .setConfig(restAssuredConfig)
            .build();
```

Now it sends output to Log4j file as we expected. The key was to add "logResponseTo" and "logRequestTo" the filters.